# Laravel app serving resources that do not exist?

Tags: css, laravel, templates, caching, view

I am in the process of adding a Content Security Policy for a laravel application. While downloading external css and font styles to the local assets I have run into some odd template behavior.

I wanted to test that the paths to the newly downloaded libraries were correct, but when I change the name of files I downloaded and refresh, even with the browser cache disabled, it is still referencing the old location successfully. If you try to access the file in the old location directly by file path it fails (because it no longer exists).

Even more strangely, if I pull the code down to another computer and run it (I have not added the new libraries to git yet), the page still seems to think it correctly loaded that resource.

I tried clearing the following directories: 
 storage/framework/cache
 storage/framework/sessions
 storage/framework/views

and running the code again - on multiple computers, and it still reports that it is loading these files that are no longer there?

Does Laravel or commonly used front end frameworks with it store compiled templates somewhere else? I am completely perplexed...

Comment: Have you tried  the `php artisan cache:clear` command?

Comment: yes I tried that already doesn't fix it :-(